# How can I find the balance point between two adjacent objects?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, mass

I want to find the balance point between two masses (in this case they happen to be 2112.7g and 1554.9g). I know how to find the balance point when these weights are considered points on a meter stick, however, these are right next to each other. Each object is 5cm wide (2D, for now).

I know the balance point is going to end up sitting under the 2kg object, off-center, but I don't know how to actually find where under that object it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with dealing with point objects, you can find the centers of gravity of each of the 2D objects (you can place the end of each of them at 0 on the x-axis) and then go on to find the center of gravity of the two resultant points.

I have used the term 'center of gravity' since you mentioned 'balance point'. However, if you consider acceleration due to gravity g to be the same everywhere, the center of gravity coincides with the center of mass.

Assuming that the distribution of masses in the 2D objects is uniform (since you have provided no other information) the center of mass for each object lies right at the center of each of them.
Hence, you will end up with 2 point objects with the given masses, 5 cm (each point 2.5cm away from the '0' on the x-axis) apart.

Comment: Thanks! I did what you suggested and used [omni calculator's 2D center of mass calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/center-of-mass) to help find the CoG. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it helped! However, I would suggest manual calculations for beginners for better understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

You will find that the COG of the 2 'point masses' lies on the line joining them, and inversely proportional to the ratio of the masses.
e.g. if you had a mass of 2 and a mass of 4 then the COG would be 2/6 along the line from the larger (and therefore 4/6 from the smaller...)